# SAML — how to process a request?

Tags: saml

I'm a newbie at SAML. My question is simple:

Upon a SAML request, what do IdPs usually do?

I guess they first parse the XML — and then? Can anybody describe the steps? I mean the common steps, that every IdP has to do at the very least.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean SAML 2 instead of SAML 1...?

Comment: What are you meant to be doing with SAML? SAML is a big topic. Which part of it do you need help with?

Comment: SAML2; just the authentication. SSO

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia article on this actually contains a lot of the information you need:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0

Look at the example SAML 2.0 Auth Request and Response plus the list of steps involved.  The simplest method is the "SP POST Request IdP POST Response" so start with that.  It's not the only option for deploying SAML 2.0, there's others also described there as well.  Hope that helps.